# Visual SourceSafe Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, dos, visual-sourcesafe

I'm using the following script to run source safe from command line on scheduled tasks to backup all the projects and files daily. The script is running correctly but it always skips 4 folders each time - the same 4 folders.

I searched a lot and I tried to modify the code but the same thing. Does any one know what may be the problem?

Here is the script:

```
@echo off


FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i IN ('date /t') DO SET DATE=%%j-%%i-%%k


SET ssuser=admin
SET sspass=**********
SET ssdir=\\10.1.43.106\DewanWork
SET ssbakd=\\10.1.43.42\SSBackup\%DATE%
SET ssmail=
SET smtp=

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%t in ('CD') DO @SET thisDir=%%t

REM --------------------------------------------------------
REM Start outputting to log
REM --------------------------------------------------------

@ss Workfold $/ %ssbakd% -Y%ssuser%,%sspass% -Oworkfold.txt
FOR /F "delims= " %%e IN ('TYPE workfold.txt') DO IF "%%e"=="Invalid" GOTO                             WorkFoldError
DEL /Q workfold.txt

REM --------------------------------------------------------
REM Get latest versions of all project files recursively
REM ----------------------------------`enter code here`----------------------
@ss Get $/* -R -I-Y -Y%ssuser%,%sspass% -Oget.txt
FOR /F "delims= " %%e IN ('TYPE get.txt') DO IF "%%e"=="Invalid" GOTO GetError
DEL /Q get.txt

@echo "" >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
DIR %ssbakd% | FIND "Dir(s)" >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
@echo %time% - Finished sourcesafe backup >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
GOTO FinishUp

:WorkFoldError
@echo Error occured while setting working folder: >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
TYPE workfold.txt >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
DEL /Q workfold.txt
GOTO SendMail

:GetError
@echo Error occured while getting project files: >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
TYPE get.txt >> "sourcesafe_%DATE%_log.txt"
DEL /Q get.txt

:SendMail
IF "%ssmail%"=="" GOTO FinishUp
IF "%smtp%"=="" GOTO FinishUp


:FinishUp
@echo %time%: Finished backup
@echo on
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked permissions on the folders (and files in the folders) that the script skips?